# Upload images to a different domain nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, file-upload, express, cors

**Background**

I tried to use [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload#cors) module to upload the images from localhost:3000 to localhost:9000 which I assume they are different domain and should belongs to **CORS** (Cross-origin resource sharing). I see [this module supports CORS](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload#user-content-cors). I also follow the express server setup that they recommend [here](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload/wiki/node.js-example). but still I can not see anything in either the body object or files object in the request.

**Questions**

1. Since this module supports CORS, why seems still not work.
2. Should I explicitly tell node server to set up something in the responds header like
   (Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers)
   and how to do that in express ?
   res.setHeader(.....) ?
3. How can I fix this problem?

**Code**

```
/* ***************************** ANGULAR ***************************************** */
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angularFileUpload']);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', [ '$scope', '$upload', function($scope, $upload) {
  $scope.$watch('files', function(files) {
    if (files) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.files.length; i++) {
          var file = $scope.files[i];
          $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
            url: 'http://localhost:9000/upload/',
            data: {myObj: $scope.myModelObj},
            file: file,
          }).progress(function(evt) {
            console.log('progress: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total) + '% file :'+ evt.config.file.name);
          }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'is uploaded successfully. Response: ' + data);
          });
        }
    }
  });
}]);

/* ***************************** SERVER SIDE ***************************************** */
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var _ = require('underscore');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.use(multipart({
    uploadDir: './uploads'
}));

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.files); // {} why ????
    console.log(req.body); // {} why ????
});

app.listen(9000);
```

Comment: try res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

Comment: @Dinesh unfortunately, it does not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I figure it out by using a middleware called [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors). so the server code looks like this

```
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express();

app.use(multipart({
    uploadDir: './uploads'
}));

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// cors middleware
app.use(cors());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.files); // then there is something : )
    next();
});

app.listen(9000);
```